# Passing array of arguments to Quartz Scheduler

Tags: java, command-line-arguments, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to add a Quartz Scheduler to an existing Java class.

The class uses `String[]` args as input from the main function.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   //validate(args);
   summarizeData(args);
}
```

But then the Java class implements `Job`, and it has to use the `execute` method which only takes one argument.

```
public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {
   // How to get the String[] args and pass it to this execute method?
   // Then I can pass it to the next helper functions, etc.
   // summarizeData(args);
}
```

Any suggestions?

Edit 1: The args should be command-line arguments in `String`

Comment: You may want to add to your question what you're passing into `main` (e.g. what is `args` and why do you need it in execute)

Comment: @Avantol13 the arguments are two dates (start_date, end_date) in String.I need it in execute because other helper functions, such as summarizeData() uses it as input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.

I had to map the command-line arguments to `JobDataMap` in the scheduler class. Then use `getJobDataMap()` in the `.execute` method to retrieve the arguments and putting them back into a `String[]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add object into the scheduler context

```
scheduler.getContext().put("arg1", "value1"); //or loop through your args
```

And then retrieve it:

```
public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {
    String arg1 = null;
    try {
        arg1 = (String)jobExecutionContext.getScheduler().getContext().get("arg1");
        //Do something
    } catch (SchedulerException e) {
        //Error management
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, depending on what kind of arguments are being passed in (and the class you're creating) it may be advantageous to just create new static class variables and set them within `main`. If you need non-static variables, you may need to modify your class constructor and accessor/mutator (getter/setter) methods to set those.

**Option I - Static Variables?**

This will only work if the variables will be the same across all instances of the class!!

Also, I don't know exactly how Quartz works, so heed my warning in the code comments.

```
public class YourClass extends Job
{
    // Your other class variables

    // New static variables
    private static String someVariable;
    private static String someOtherVariable;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        someVariable = args[0]; //<---- Set class variables
        someOtherVariable = args[1];

        // Do other stuff
    }

    // WARNING: If main isn't called (from any instance) before execute
    // the class variables will still be null
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {
       // Do stuff with someVariable and someOtherVariable 
       System.out.println(someVariable + " " + someOtherVariable);
   }
}
```

**Option II - Non-static Variables**

Depending on your implementation, you may want to set the variables outside of `main` so they're not static. In that case, just create non-static class variables and modify your constructor to set these when the object is created (and/or add accessor/mutator (getter/setter) methods to modify the variables after initialization).

Since I don't know how you're using this class, I don't know which of the above two options will work best.

Comment: `static` is fine, but `main` isn't called at all when there is `execute`. Can I still take in command-line arguments if I set the variables outside of `main`?